# Delete Column Rows with Any Numeric Substrings

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, delete-row, isnumeric

I notice that when an element of a column from a Pandas DataFrame has numeric substrings, the method `isnumeric` returns false.

For example:

```
row 1, column 1 has the following: 0002 0003 1289
row 2, column 1 has the following: 89060 324 123431132
row 3, column 1 has the following: 890GB 32A 34311TT
row 4, column 1 has the following: 82A 34311TT
row 4, column 1 has the following: 82A 34311TT 889 9999C
```

Clearly, the rows 1 and 2 are all numbers, but `isnumeric` returns false for rows 1 and 2.

I found a work-around the involves separating each substring into their own columns and then creating a boolean column for each to add the booleans together to reveal whether a row is all numeric or not. This, however, is tedious and my function doesn't look tidy. I also to not want to strip and replace the whitespace (to squeeze all the substrings into just one number) because I need to preserve the original substrings.

Does anyone know of a simpler solution/technique that will correctly tell me that these elements with one or more numeric sub strings is all numeric? My ultimate goal is to delete these numeric-only rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need list comprehension with `split` with `all` for check all numeric strings:

```
mask = ~df['a'].apply(lambda x: all([s.isnumeric() for s in x.split()]))
```

---

```
mask = [not all([s.isnumeric() for s in x.split()]) for x in df['a']]
```

If want check if at least one numeric string use `any`:

```
mask = ~df['a'].apply(lambda x: any([s.isnumeric() for s in x.split()]))
```

---

```
mask = [not any([s.isnumeric() for s in x.split()]) for x in df['a']]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am avoiding any stripping of whitespaces. I am not quite sure what you are doing there with the first one. Where does the s come from in the s.isnumeric? Because I am getting '''str' has no attribute 'isnumeric'.

Comment: My code:mask = ~df['ORGNTR_ACCT_ID'].apply(lambda x: all([str.isnumeric() for s in x.split()]))... that is the column with the rows of substrings.

Comment: @spacedustpi - You working with splitted strings, so need `s.isnumeric()` not `str.isnumeric()`

Comment: @spacedustpi explanation - For each value first split it by whitespaces and for each splitted value check if numeric. It return list of boolean, so need `all` for check if all vslues are `True`.

Comment: Thanks jezrael, this works in my python 3.6 environment! I actually just started a tutorial on masking at datacamp.com like two days ago, but didn't finish it yet. :)

Comment: @spacedustpi - Glad can help! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `pd.Series.map`, `any` with a generator expression, `str.isdecimal` and `str.split`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['0002 0003 1289', '89060 324 123431132', '890GB 32A 34311TT',
                            '82A 34311TT', '82A 34311TT 889 9999C']})

df['numeric'] = df['col1'].map(lambda x: any(i.isdecimal() for i in x.split()))
```

Note that `isdecimal` is [more strict](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/02/python-isdigit-vs-isdecimal/) than `isdigit`. But you may need to use `str.isdigit` or `str.isnumeric` in Python 2.7.

To remove such rows where result is `False`:

```
df = df[df['col1'].map(lambda x: any(i.isdecimal() for i in x.split()))]
```

**Result**

First part of logic:

```
                    col1 numeric
0         0002 0003 1289    True
1    89060 324 123431132    True
2      890GB 32A 34311TT   False
3            82A 34311TT   False
4  82A 34311TT 889 9999C    True
```

Comment: Thanks, which version of python are you using? I get the error message: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isdecimal'.

Comment: @spacedustpi, good point. I have 3.6, so you may have to use `str.isnumeric` or `str.isdigit`.

Comment: So this code runs in my conda python 3.6 environment, however, why is index=4 coming up true? Clearly it is not numeric. Only substring '889' is numeric.

Comment: So you need to replace `any` with `all` for this logic.

Comment: You beat me to it. That is what just I did (duh) and it worked, thanks!